# Laravel 3 JSON and jQuery getJSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, laravel

I'm trying to get a JSON result from a laravel-project.

I have a jquery app on my webhotel, trying to access my laravel api on another server.
Everytime i use getJSON in my js, I get the following error in firebug:

```
Object { 
  readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error"
}
```

I my laravel controller I'm using this to produce the json:

```
$article = News::with('Category', 'Author')->find($id);
return Response::json($article, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/javascript'));
```

It would be really great, if someone could point me in the right direction. Maybe it's something about having the jquery app and laravel api on two different servers?

Comment: see if this helps: [same origin policy?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) and [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Answer (score 0):

the content type for `json` should be

```
array('Content-Type' => 'application/json')
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the first param should be required. It will set the headers and response code automatically. The other issue is that the model is actually quite a bit more complex then what you probably want to return. Try the following.

```
return Response::json( $article->to_array() );
```